How to eliminate the verbose pattern of canActivate/canDeactivate in Angular?
My routing is set up like this (main parent node with a bunch of child sub nodes).
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
  { path: "profile", component: ProfileComponent },
  {
    path: ":itemId", component: TabsComponent, children: [
      { path: "a", component: ComponentA, canActivate: [MsalGuard], canDeactivate: guard },
      { path: "b", component: ComponentB, canActivate: [MsalGuard], canDeactivate: guard },
      { path: "c", component: ComponentC, canActivate: [MsalGuard], canDeactivate: guard },
      ...
    ], canActivate: [MsalGuard]
  },
  ...
  { path: "**", component: BoomComponent },
];

I noticed that the canActivate: [MsalGuard] for the tabs (i.e. the last one) isn't really useful, because each sub-placed child has it too. Then, it stroke me: is there a way to specify canActivate and canDeactivate so that it actually influence the individual sub-paths?
Something along the lines of the below (which I, naturally, tested and discovered that it won't do what I want).
...
{
  path: ":itemId", component: TabsComponent, children: [
    { path: "a", component: ComponentA },
    { path: "b", component: ComponentB },
    { path: "c", component: ComponentC },
    ...
    ], canActivate: [MsalGuard], canDeactivate: guard
  ...
}


From the MSAL Guard  - Github Documentation the MsalGuard Supports CanActivateChild and canLoad. So could you try CanActivateChild guard instead of canActivate.
...
{
  path: ":itemId", component: TabsComponent, children: [
    { path: "a", component: ComponentA },
    { path: "b", component: ComponentB },
    { path: "c", component: ComponentC },
    ...
    ], canActivateChild: [MsalGuard], canDeactivate: guard
  ...
}


That's an excellent suggestion. I'll try that later today. I'm hoping that there's also the corresponding for deactivation, i.e. canDeactivateChild that can be set for the parent route but affect all the children routes.

@KonradViltersten unfortunately there is no canDeactivateChild, but you can try for canactivate

Darn... I just noticed that myself. Such a disappointment. Is there a way to hack it in? Or simply wait hoping that it's introduced in the future versions?

@KonradViltersten importing it is best for now, maybe in future it will be available, but mostly no
